# Is there any subscription payment api in android ,user has to pay every two months , in order to access app service?

Tags: android, subscribe

I have developed an application , where it provide some services to user. he has to subscribe before for 2 months , 4 months like that , he can update it by paying . Can any one tell me , is there any api provided to serve the above purpose . ??

Thank you,

Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently having the same problem. Afaik, there is no such API from Google. What I am gonna do is use PayPal for it. There is no Subscription, but at least a lot of users have a PayPal account and don't have to type in their credit card number.

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep

Answer (score 0):

In an App I developed I'm using a payment providers view. It works good enough, you can check it in the Bluppr Postcards App.

The payment provider I'm using is Adyen, Adyen supports multiple payment methods.

Comment: I can't find Bluppr Postcards anymore in the play store, where is it?